# Atomic update of 2 Couchbase documents

Tags: document, couchbase, atomic, spring-data-couchbase

Could you please give me a hint is there any way to atomically update multiple documents on the Couchbase using Java SDK? I know, it's possible to use Embedding of documents, thus guaranteeing required, but, unfortunately, it doesn't work out for me.

In my case, the fact of document update leads to the fact that it's needed to invalidate (set special flag to false) other document, and it should be performed atomically.

I appreciate any help or suggestions from your side. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no built-in way to perform atomic changes to multiple documents, you can use [two-phase commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) to achieve the same result. Note that in this case 2PC doesn't provide other transactional features, like isolation and consistency, only atomicity - which is what you're asking for. There is no reference 2PC implementation in Java for Couchbase, but there are two in Ruby and PHP in the documentation. I recommend reading the docs on [providing transactional logic](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/transactional-logic.html) in Couchbase for an in-depth description of how to implement this. Porting the example code to Java should be fairly straightforward.

Generally speaking, to implement a set of changes on multiple documents atomically, you perform atomic writes to each document in turn, plus a temporary "state" document, in such a way that each step in the process is unique. This way you're able to continue from the same step or roll back your changes if the transaction gets interrupted in the middle for any reason.

Comment: Hi David! Thank you for your answer!
Looks interesting! Will try to investigate that!

I guess, it's the best effort so far...
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that boils down to a transaction, and Couchbase doesn't offer native transaction support. The level of atomicity you can achieve with Couchbase is at the level of a single document.

I know that some couchbase users have implemented manual transaction management in their applicative code layer, but that's quite a complicated topic and there's no openly available solution that I know of.